# Have two version Git in my desktop

Tags: linux, git, centos-7

I use CentOS 7, yesterday i update my version of Git from 1.8.3.1 to 2.17.1 but i have problem.

when i use sudo su, the version is still 1.8.3.1 but when i not use sudo su the version is 2.17.1 like this:

```
[misdan@localhost ~]$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
[misdan@localhost ~]$ cd opt/
bash: cd: opt/: No such file or directory
[misdan@localhost ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for misdan: 
[root@localhost misdan]# git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`? What tells you `which git` when you run it misdan and what if you run it as root?

Comment: if i use sudo -i and type git --version the version is 1.8.3.1 but when i not use root version of git is 2.17.1

Comment: And what about the output of `which git`? It is possible to use two different versions of git on the same machine, but if you run `git` it must be the same version, except if the older version is ahead newer in root user's PATH . AFAIK.

Comment: there is no difference only I am worried when doing basic commands Git with superuser errors will occur because the version is still 1.8

Comment: Hm. How did you upgrade(?) git?  I've found only git 1.8.3.1 in CentOS 7's official repo. Could you paste here the output of `whereis git` both from root, and your own shell?

Comment: Just I've tried to upgrade git on my CentOS vm,  using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-7-x-6-x.  After installing git 2 I have only one instance of git, and it is the latest 2.x.x...